# Trying to run a simple program to count how many even numbers an array has

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am trying to make a program to simply count even numbers and display it to the user, but I am getting the wrong output.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  int par = 0;
  int tam;
  int arr [ ] = {};

  cin >> tam;

   for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++ ){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++ ){
        cout << arr[i];
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        if (arr[i]%2 == 0) {
            par++;
      }

      cout << par;

    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Fix your indentation and you'll immediately spot the issue.

Comment: and just to add something on the side, `int arr [ ] = {};` this is not standard c++

Comment: Also, share some of your actual output and what you're expecting. Any kind of errors or output helps.

Comment: You don't need an array.  Count the even's and odd's after each number that you input.

Answer (score 1):

Your code exhibits *undefined behavior*, as you are creating an empty array and then trying to write values to it outside of its bounds.  Since you don't know at compile-time how many numbers the user will be entering at runtime, use a `std::vector` instead of an array.

Also, you have the `cout << par;` and `return 0;` statements in the wrong place.  You have them *inside* the final loop, when they should be *after* the loop instead.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int par = 0;
    int tam, num;
    vector<int> vec;

    cin >> tam;

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; ++i){
        cin >> num;
        vec.push_back(num);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; ++i){
        cout << vec[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; ++i){
        if (vec[i] % 2 == 0) {
            ++par;
        }
    }

    cout << par;

    return 0;
}
```

You could then eliminate the last loop entirely by using the standard `std::count_if()` algorithm instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int tam, num;
    vector<int> vec;

    cin >> tam;

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; ++i){
        cin >> num;
        vec.push_back(num);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; ++i){
        cout << vec[i];
    }

    cout << count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
        [](int num){ return num % 2 == 0; }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Although, you don't actually need the array/vector at all, you can just count values as the user is entering them, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int par = 0;
    int tam, num;

    cin >> tam;

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; ++i){
        cin >> num;
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            ++par;
        }
    }

    cout << par;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing a closing curly brace to end the last loop. You will loop only one time through it, show the output and return 0. You need to change to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
{
  if(arr[i] % 2 == 0)
  {
    par++;
  }
}
```